# Java: Unique Items in an array

Tags: java, arrays, unique

I can't seem to wrap my brain around this, but lets say I'm given an array with different elements in it. If I wanted to create another array with only the unique elements from the first array, how would I go about doing that without using Maps, HashSets etc (without importing anything else from java).

Comment: You need a way to know if an object is *unique*, so you can *trust* in `Object#equals` or a `java.util.Comparator` in order to check if the object to be inserted is already in your array.

Comment: Write your own method of sorting, and loop through it? If you can import java.util.Arrays, then you can sort the array and loop through it to remove duplicate.

Comment: You could sort the array, iterate over it and populate the new array in a single loop. Complexity: `O(N*logN)`.

Comment: @harpun:+1, Great idea.But he doesn't to import anything from java. So he would have to implement sorting I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Simple brute force algorithm.
Just (double) loop over the array and check if is element is repeated or not. If not add it to the array and continue. `O(N^2)` complexity instead of `O(N)` complexity using a `Map` or `Set`

Comment: O(N) is only achievable with `HashMap`. It will be O(Nlog N) with `TreeMap`

Comment: @nhahtdh `O(N)` using a `Map`? I though it was `O(1)`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: The N is for the N elements in the array. Operation on HashMap (add) is O(1) amortized.

Comment: This will work, but O(N^2) is kind of slow. Doing a sort on the array first, and then looping through would give O(N*lgN).
Edit: Harpun's comment above gives this as answer. Just noticed.  That's the best solution I think.

Comment: @2to1mux:I agree sorting is better.But the OP says he does not want to import anything.So he would have to implement one of the sorting methods for this

Answer (score 0):

Please don't up-vote this, see Cratylus's answer - or better, harpun's comment. This is just some "pseudocode" *for a solution with O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity*.

---

```
foreach element1 in array:
    duplicate = false
    foreach element2 in array:
        if element 1 == element 2:
            duplicate = true
            break // out of inner loop
    if duplicate:
       // duplicate
    else:
       // not duplicate
```

Of course this can be more cleanly expressed at a slightly higher level. The definition of "contains" should be evident.

```
foreach element in array:
   if contains(array, element):
       // duplicate
```